# What HEREMaps plan should I choose to be able to perform revers geocoding batch request?

Tags: here-api, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying to perform a batch request which is expected to convert few tens of coordinates into addresses. I'm executing it on a "Freemium" plan, but I'm getting 403 error and a message telling me that my plan doesn't support that service.

I'm developing a server which is going to execute few hundred of that same type requests per day. I wrote to the support of HEREMaps to explain me what plan should I use and am waiting for their answer. Meanwhile I hope to find someone here who has run into the same problem and can shed some light on it.

Let say I need to perform 500 batch requests daily with 10 geographical points each. What HEREMaps plan will work for me and what is the average price of that type of services?

This is my URL for the POST request (REST API):

```
https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs?apiKey={MY_API_Key}&action=run&header=true&indelim=|&outdelim=|&outcols=displayLatitude,displayLongitude,locationLabel,houseNumber,street,district,city,postalCode,county,state,country&outputCombined=false&mode=retrieveAddresses
```

With header:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

The body:

```
recId|prox
0|24.3513483,42.1014
1|24.35171,42.1016533
2|24.3515583,42.1015266
3|24.3507683,42.1045716
```

Response - Forbidden 403:

```
{"error":"Forbidden","error_description":"These credentials do not authorize access. Please contact your customer
representative or email locationapi@here.com to discuss upgrading your account."}
```

Comment: Batch reverse geocoding REST API should available to Freemium plan. Are you using REST API? If yes, could you provide the exact API call used, and we can check little more.

Comment: @HERE Developer Support,  Please see my the question again. I have provided additional details.

Comment: Please use correct REST API Key as this request is working correctly when tested.

Comment: There is only one REST API key in my Freemium account and I used it in the request above. I only replaced my real API key with the string {MY_API_Key}. I took the API key from here - https://developer.here.com/projects. See that screenshot https://ibb.co/qjwWnXm . Isn't that the correct REST API Key?

Comment: @HERE Developer Support, I successfully execute a multi-reverse gecode request from your Geocoder API, but failed to execute a job request from your Batch Geocoder API with the same credentials. Am I supposed to do so with my Freemium account?

Comment: One possible cause for such kind issue could be that you already running out of your allocated free transactions. Could you provide your app_id, so we can have a check on your account?

Comment: Sure, here it is eKKRoHGQ751njdv20Q75

Comment: Run a check on your account, everything seems to be normal. Account is not locked, all batch services included. Also checked your transaction, only about 300+ transactions and far below the 250k limitation. By any chance,  you are using oAuth token?

Comment: No, I'm not. I only use the apiKey that is provided in my account as shown in the image -  https://ibb.co/qjwWnXm. That is the code laying under the green mark. Using Postman (https://www.postman.com/), every time I send a POST request as described above and I get 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

this is the plan you need to execute: https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-batch-geocode.html

If you already signed with freemium plan, double check when you did that as HERE is changing their price plans, where they double in some cases the price tag  and keep same freemium plan on the surface but with the new price tag and the old plan is not showing any longer.

https://developer.here.com/pricing#freemium--pro-plans